# amd ryzen 5950x max frequency is 3400MHz on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cpu, cpufreq, amd-ryzen

When I run `lscpu`, I get

```
CPU max MHz: 3400.0000
CPU min MHz: 2200.0000
```

However, 5950x has a base frequency of 3400MHz and max of 4900MHz. How do I let ubuntu know that it can run up to 4900MHz?

EDIT:
In BIOS, it says that my cpu is running at 3400MHz, but when I check it from the terminal, I get 2192.157MHz...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 uses the 5.4 kernel, which doesn’t fully take advantage of the 5950x. You’ll need 5.8 to eke out more performance or, ideally, 5.10 which has better support for the thermal throttling. Ubuntu 20.10 has the 5.8 kernel built in, so the simplest option may be to update to that version. 5.10 or higher will likely be part of 21.04 when it comes out in April. 5.11 looks like it’s getting a lot of AMD-centric updates, too.

Comment: @Matigo Ahh I see. I think I'll wait for the 21.04 updates. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

When you run the computer with heavy load, you get a boost value.

```
p-i@pi-TUF-Gaming-B550M:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          12
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-11
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      25
Model:                           33
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor
Stepping:                        0
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         4418.048
CPU max MHz:                     3700,0000
CPU min MHz:                     2200,0000
BogoMIPS:                        7399.78
```

There is more information about Frequency boost on this page
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt
To enable Frequency boost you have to do a setting in BIOS. On my motherboard this setting is in AMD CBS and called Core Performance Boost.

Comment: I have yet to run anything heavy yet, but I'll give this a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Fedora 34 (kernel 5.11) and have the same issue. First off, you need to set an option in the BIOS to allow overclocking, can't remember what it's called on my ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero but it's Core Boost or something.

I use "cpu-x" to create an artificial load and "nmon" (press M) to monitor the frequencies.

Once booted, "cpupower frequency-info" will tell you what each CPU can do. It's strange that some of my CPUs have a hardware limit of 6.7Ghz. Anyway, once you're monitoring try "sudo cpupower frequency-set --max 490000" and you should see the nmon Mhz go up. You can also use "--max 7000000" but on my machine nothing reached 4.7Ghz

If there's a better way, I'd like to know.

Paul